# txtbox string and innerText/innerHTML (HTMLAGILITYPACK) are returning a false comparison

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have pulled some information from the internet using HTMLAGilityPack. No problem.
I then pass the innerHTML through a method I took from stackoverflow (this is to remove mark ups etc and make it plaintext).

I then call a boolean to determine if the new output is the same as a txtInput on the form. It is returning false even though they are the same?

I know nothing about unicode, UT-8, Cry, character bytes etc.. Though i'm assuming the binary are different? even though they appear the same? How can I get around this problem.

This is the string in the input box, the same one it pulls from HTMLAGilitypack
"When I Grow Up (feat. Lauren Ward & Bailey Ryon)"

This is the 2 outputs side by side.

[image: Input Value]
[image: Node Value]

As you can see from the pictures, face value they look exactly the same. Yet it returns false. Please how can I fix this?

Here is my code:

This checks if the values are different and always returns false.

```
private bool CheckText(string node)
    {
        string value = HtmlToPlainText(txtSong.Text);  
        if (value == node)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This is the method that actually pulls the data, If it matches it will open the page, if it doesn't it retry.

```
private void pullTable(int pageNum, string keyWord, int resultStart)
    {
        int countCheck = 0;
        while (countCheck == 0)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            string amazon = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Ddigital-music&page=" + pageNum + "";

            if (txtSong.Text != "")
            {
                string temp = txtSong.Text.Replace("(", "%28");
                temp = temp.Replace(")", "%26");
                amazon = amazon + "&field-keywords=" + temp;
            }
            if (txtArtist.Text != "")
            {
                string temp = txtArtist.Text.Replace("(", "%28");
                temp = temp.Replace(")", "%26");
            amazon = amazon + "&field-author=" + temp;
            }
            if (radioArtistAZ.Checked)
                amazon = amazon + "&sort=artist-album-asc-rank";
            else if (radioArtistZA.Checked)
                amazon = amazon + "&sort=artist-album-desc-rank";
            else if (radioSongAZ.Checked)
                amazon = amazon + "&sort=title-asc-rank";
            else if (radioSongZA.Checked)
                amazon = amazon + "&sort=title-desc-rank";
            {

            }

            var doc = web.Load(amazon);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body");
            try
            {
                nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[starts-with(@id, 'result_')]/td[2]/div/a");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    //    string tempValue = nodes[i].InnerHtml.Replace("&amp;", "&");
                    var plainText = HtmlToPlainText(nodes[i].InnerText);
                    if (CheckText(plainText))
                    {
                        AppendTextBox("Opening on page " + pageNum);
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(amazon);
                        found = 1;
                        countCheck = 1;
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {


                    }
                }
                countCheck = 1;
                AppendTextBox("Not found on page " + pageNum);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                AppendTextBox("error on page " + pageNum);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I should also clarify, If the string for example is just text. It works fine. It is only when the string contains special characters... So in this case (feat. Lauren Ward & Bailey Ryon) seems to be causing the bool to return false. If there were no bracket or & symbols. it would match up fine. Even though I pass the innerHTML through the other method to remove all the mark ups?

Comment: Try to use `value.Equals(node, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` [String.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: HI Anamnian, That did work.. However, The search needs to be case sensitive. As the results i'm pulling need to be an exact match. Would you know why this seemed to work? Putting everything in uppercase did make it return true but its strange as they were already the same? Or at least they appeared to be...

Comment: If you need case sensitive you need use `StringComparison.Ordinal` as comparisonType.
`value.Equals(node, StringComparison.Ordinal)`

Comment: omg im blind. I just took a good look and noticed a difference. The U is capital vs the u lowercase in the other...

Thank you for your help anyway :). I wouldn't of spotted that without knowing what to look for.